# Correctly chaining Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to bind promises sequentially, inside a loop. I need this to user accounts, where the result of one operation depends on another.
I am trying to write a flat version - all code in one place, using bind. That's at least what I wanted. I wrapped promises around two create methods, as below:

```
function create(myApi, record) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            myApi.create(record, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) reject(err);
                    else resolve(result);
            });
    });
}

function createUser(myApi, record) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            myApi.createUser(record, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) reject(err);
                    else resolve(result);
            });
    });
}
```

Now, I want to create users in a loop as:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < dummyData.accounts.length; i++) {
  var cursorUser = dummyData.accounts[i];
  var auth0User = {
    email: cursorUser.email,
    password: cursorUser.password,
    connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication'
  };
  createUser(api, auth0User)
    .then( function(auth0Info) {
      console.log("Auth0 userInfo: ", auth0Info);
      cursorUser.authProfile = auth0Info;
      create(accountsAPIService, cursorUser)
        .then(function (account) {
          console.log("created account:", account);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log('count not create account for user, error: ', err, '\nfor: ', auth0User);
        });
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('could not create auth0 user, error: ', err, '\nfor: ', auth0User);
  });
}
```

Since the two method are asynchronous, it is of course not working correctly. Calls are not executed sequentially. I want to chain promises so that create does not run until a call from createUser returned. Tried using bind, but it did not work for me. It is how one should do the sequential chaining? I bind on .then of the createUser? Please advise.

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-10/advanced-promise-usage/

Comment: Hey is ES6 an option?if so moving to generators would make your life so much easier

Comment: @itai
Thank you for noticing my question. ES6 might be an option. Regardless, I would love to know how this could be done with ES6, if nothing else.

Comment: @MosheShmukler wrote answer hope it will help

Comment: @itai
Yes, thank you. I believe that I figured out how to use bind, but it is definitely nice to know how things could work under es6. At work, my colleagues do lots of typescript->es6->es5 with babel. It is too advanced for me at the moment, but I will certainly try to understand your example.

Answer (score 3):

When you return a promise from a `then`, the `then` chained after will resolve/reject with that promise instead of the original promise.

```
createUser(api, auth0User).then(function(auth0Info) {
  cursorUser.authProfile = auth0Info;

  // Return create's promise
  return create(accountsAPIService, cursorUser);

}, function (err) {
  console.log('could not create auth0 user, error: ', err, '\nfor: ', auth0User);
})
// This will wait for create's promise instead of createUser's promise
.then(function (account) {
  console.log("created account:", account);
}, function (err) {
  console.log('count not create account for user, error: ', err, '\nfor: ', auth0User);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not positive that you are correct, here. At least my data looks wrong. I might be messing it up myself. From my tests, it does not look like the loop is waiting.

Comment: I am pretty sure that these promises are being executed in parallel and not sequentially. Yet, I know nothing about this and still don't understand the subject. I might be wrong.

Comment: you were nearly on the spot. First then needs to be replaced for bind.

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 you can use generators which allows you to do write async task as they were async. In this example i am using bluebird but ofc there are others great valid options.

```
var CreateUserGenerator = BPromise.coroutine(function * (arg) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < dummyData.accounts.length; i++) {
      var cursorUser = dummyData.accounts[i];
      var auth0User = {
        email: cursorUser.email,
        password: cursorUser.password,
        connection: 'Username-Password-Authentication'
    };
    var auth0Info =  yield createUser(api, auth0User);
    console.log("Auth0 userInfo: ", auth0Info);
    cursorUser.authProfile = auth0Info;
    var account = yield create(accountsAPIService, cursorUser)
    console.log("created account:", account);         
    }
}

function generateorWithCatch (argument) {
    creatLoopUser(arg)
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('could not create auth0 user, error: ', err, '\nfor: ', auth0User);
    });
}
```

In this solution i assume your create and createUser functions are written and return value correctly